# Wordpress Communicate b/w js file and functions.php without using wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone tell me that how I pass or post my javascript variables to functions.php file method without using enqueue js files.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is your `script` tag in the source code of your page ?

Comment: Your code is working fine in my local.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for enqueue script in wordpress

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mycustom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1.0', true );    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Or

```
function wpdocs_custom_enqueue() {
    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#checkbox").click(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //Do stuff
            alert("It is checked");

        } else {
            alert("it is not checked");

        }
    }); 
});</script>\n';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpdocs_custom_enqueue' );
```

Both codes are working.